# Cannot populate array within an array -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have an array within an array. It is called r0w. Here's what it looks like:

```
r0w[0] = [1,38,0,63,20,39,1,36,36,36,34,35,35,36,36,37,1]
r0w[1] = [1,38,63,124,20,101,1,36,36,36,34,35,35,36,36,37,1]
r0w[2] = [1,38,124,185,20,162,1,36,36,36,34,35,35,36,36,37,1]
r0w[3] = [1,48,185,248,25,224,1,44,37,103,35,92,1]
```

Now I want to perform some calculations on these arrays within arrays and output it to another array within an array called absw1dth. Here is my code.

```
var absw1dth = [[]];

for (e=0 ; e < r0w.length ; e++ ) {
    absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
    for (f=8 ; f < r0w[e].length ; f++ ) {
        absw1dth[e][f - 7] = (r0w[e][f] + absw1dth[e][f - 8]);
        };
    };
```

It keeps error-ing out at this line

```
absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
```

and says undefined is not an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the initialization of your `abswidth`. You've done this

```
var absw1dth = [[]];
```

...which will create an array with one element, another array with no elements. So when `e` is `1` (rather than `0`), the expression `absw1dth[e][0]` is trying to index into an array `abswidth[1]` that doesn't exist.

If the data is as static as you've shown (there will always only be four rows in the `r0w` array), you could solve it with initialization:

```
var absw1dth = [ [], [], [], [] ];
```

Now `abswidth` is a four-element array, where each element is an empty array.

But if the data is more dynamic, I'd probably initialize on-the-fly:

```
var absw1dth = []; // Just an empty array

for (e=0 ; e < r0w.length ; e++ ) {
    abswidth[e] = []; // Create this element
    absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
    for (f=8 ; f < r0w[e].length ; f++ ) {
        absw1dth[e][f - 7] = (r0w[e][f] + absw1dth[e][f - 8]);
        };
    };
    // ...
}
```

If it's possible that code you're not showing may have already created the array elements within `abwidth`, but also may not have, you can test first:

```
var absw1dth = []; // Just an empty array

for (e=0 ; e < r0w.length ; e++ ) {
    if (!abswidth[e]) {
        abswidth[e] = []; // Create this element
    }
    absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
    for (f=8 ; f < r0w[e].length ; f++ ) {
        absw1dth[e][f - 7] = (r0w[e][f] + absw1dth[e][f - 8]);
        };
    };
    // ...
}
```

Or go all "functional programming" and use JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
var absw1dth = []; // Just an empty array

for (e=0 ; e < r0w.length ; e++ ) {
    abswidth[e] = abswidth[e] || []; // Create this element if needed
    absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
    for (f=8 ; f < r0w[e].length ; f++ ) {
        absw1dth[e][f - 7] = (r0w[e][f] + absw1dth[e][f - 8]);
        };
    };
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, awesome answer. I'd give this two votes if I could. I ended up using the first solution you provided, but find the other two very interesting. Saved that article for later, looks very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var absw1dth = [];

for (e=0 ; e < r0w.length ; e++ ) {
    absw1dth[e] = [];
    absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );
    //...
```

Comment: Yep, this is spot on! It's the same as Jarrett's answer, but the code is more visible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`absw1dth[e][0]` is not an object because `absw1dth[e]` is not an object yet.

Try `absw1dth[e] = []; absw1dth[e][0] = ( r0w[e][7] + r0w[e][1] );`

Comment: Amazing! This worked a charm. Thanks much. So in summary, by adding the absw1dth[e] = []; line in the first part of my for loop, it creates an array within an array, and not just one, it's dynamic since it's in the for loop. That was my problem I believe, I wasn't creating the array within the array properly. Therefore I couldn't properly populate it.

Comment: Sounds like you get the idea of it.